# How to get values from bootstrap.yml file from static instance

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

- I have a classes **CosmosConnection** and **SupplierGetResponseFeed**
- I am calling the method of **CosmosConnection** from **SupplierGetResponseFeed**
- The method of **SupplierGetResponseFeed** from which I am calling **CosmosConnection** method is static
- Example  : `public static SupplierResponseDataEntity prepareSupplierAzureData(Map<String, Object> row, String[] columnNames) {`
- So , When I create the object of **CosmosConnection**  in **SupplierGetResponseFeed** I can not use `@Autowired` as a reason I am not able to pick the value from bootstrap.yml file in **CosmosConnection**
- Though I create the object using @Autowired in **SupplierGetResponseFeed**  I am not able to pick the values from bootstrap

  **@Autowired 
      static CosmosConnection cosmos;**

Below is the code for **SupplierGetResponseFeed**

```
public class SupplierGetResponseFeed {
static CosmosConnection cosmos= new CosmosConnection(); //creating object 
public static SupplierResponseDataEntity prepareSupplierAzureData(Map<String, Object> row, String[] columnNames) {
//Some code 
cosmos.connectToDB(); //calling the method of CosmosConnection class
}
```

The code for is **CosmosConnection**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class CosmosConnection {
    @Value("${cosmos.connectionuri}") private String uri;
    @Value("${cosmos.primarykey}") private String primarykey;

public String connectToDB() throws DocumentClientException, IOException, ParseException {
    System.out.println("URI is " + uri); //getting this as null
```

What changes I need to do for picking the values from bootstrap.yml ??

Answer (score 1):

A annotation called PostConstruct in package javax.annotation with spring framework can be used to solve the problem. As described in the source code:

```
The PostConstruct annotation is used on a method that needs to be executed
 after dependency injection is done to perform any initialization
```

And code below is a example:

```java
@Configuration
public class ComosConfig {
  @Value("${cosmos.connectionuri}") private String uri;
  @Value("${cosmos.primarykey}") private String primarykey;

  //get and set methods here
}
```

```java
public class CosmosConnection {
  private String uri;
  private String primaryKey;

  public CosmosConnection(String uri, String primaryKey) {
    this.uri = uri;
    this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
  } 

  public String connectToDB() {
    //do something here
  }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class SupplierGetResponseFeed {
  private static CosmosConnection cosmos;
  private CosmosConfig config;

  public SupplierGetResponseFeed(CosmosConfig config) {
    this.config = config;
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    String uri = config.getUri();
    String primaryKey = config.getprimaryKey(); 
    cosmos = new cosmos(uri, primaryKey);
  }

  public static SupplierResponseDataEntity prepareSupplierAzureData() {
    cosmos.connectToDB(); //calling the method of CosmosConnection class
  }
}
```

After all, it's not recommended in view of code analysis utils to write to static from instance method, so you may need suppress-warning-annotation used with init method to eliminate warnings.